# Image Transffer on Ejabberd Server using Secure chat app

Tags: android, ios, ejabberd

I am trying to communicate between Android and iOS app using Ejabberd Server setup at backend.

For Android I am registered with "Conversation" app. 
For iOS I am registered with "ChatSecure" app.

I am able to send image if both users are available on same app. But If one user is logged in with Android and another with iOS then image transfer not working. It gives error due to "OMEMO" encryption.

Any idea how I can remove this encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Could you say what is the difference between "Conversation" app and  "ChatSecure" app ?